# Android webView Wikipedia sections are loaded expanded

Tags: javascript, android, webview, wikipedia

I would like the sections to be closed when the web page is opened, like this: [image: closed sections]

The problem is that they are loaded in expanded mode, which makes the page very long to read.

I have enabled javaScript.

Is it possible to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the class names of the sections in the HTML.
In [Wikipedia's help section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Collapsing#Collapsing_tables_by_default), you can read about collapsing tables by default. It is very similar to what you asked for when the only difference is that you need to implement it for collapsible headings and collapsible blocks so the sections will be hidden by default.
By looking at the source code of the page you are able to see the class names of the areas you want to modify. They are called `section-heading in-block collapsible-heading` for the title and `mf-section-1 collapsible-block` for the content (where the number is different for each section). You will need to add `close-block` at the end of the class name and that will take care of what you asked for.

By using the following code you will be able to modify your web view.

This is `JavaScript` code for adding `close-block` at the end of the class name:

```
var heading = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible-heading");
for (var i = 0; i < heading.length; i++) {
    if(heading[i].classList.contains("open-block")) {
        heading[i].className = heading[i].className.replace("open-block", "close-block");
    }
    else {
        heading[i].className+= " close-block";
    }
}
var section = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible-block");
for (var i = 0; i < section.length; i++) {
    if(section[i].classList.contains("open-block")) {
        section[i].className = section[i].className.replace("open-block", "close-block");
    }
    else {
        section[i].className+= " close-block";
    }
}
```

This is the `Java` code for changing the web view on android:

```
WebView myWebViewDisply = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebViewDisply);
myWebViewDisply.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebViewDisply.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

String jsFunction=new StringBuilder()
                .append("var heading = document.getElementsByClassName(\"collapsible-heading\");\n")
                .append("for (var i = 0; i < heading.length; i++) {\n")
                .append("if(heading[i].classList.contains(\"open-block\")) {\n")
                .append("heading[i].className = heading[i].className.replace(\"open-block\", \"close-block\");\n}\n")
                .append("else {\n")
                .append("heading[i].className+= \" close-block\";\n}\n}\n")
                .append("var section = document.getElementsByClassName(\"collapsible-block\");\n")
                .append("for (var i = 0; i < section.length; i++) {\n")
                .append("if(section[i].classList.contains(\"open-block\")) {\n")
                .append("section[i].className = section[i].className.replace(\"open-block\", \"close-block\");\n}\n")
                .append("else {\n")
                .append("section[i].className+= \" close-block\";\n}\n}\n")
                .toString();

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    myWebViewDisply.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){"+jsFunction+"})()");
    }
});
myWebViewDisply.loadUrl(youUrl);
```

Note that you need to copy to your project only the `Java` code.
I wrote the `JavaScript` code separately
 for readability, the `Java` code contains inside it the `JavaScript` code needed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Wikipedia has its own mobile version. Below is the example

Web Version:
 "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Believe"

Mobile Version"
"https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Believe"

As you can see just append ".m" to the wiki url.

Comment: I was talking about the mobile version. I used links with the "m", but they are still expanded by default.

Comment: Then as far as I know , I don't think we can shrink the sections from mobile side.